# AddressOf in base class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

When referencing a method's address, should we take into account the overriding or not?

```
Class B 
  Inherits A

  Overrides Sub Foo
     Console.WriteLine("B")
  End Sub
End Class


Class A
  Public Sub PFoo
  ... AddressOf Foo ... ' WHAT WILL DO THIS METHOD??? '
  End

  Protected Overridable Sub Foo()
     Console.WriteLine("A")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You could just test this, you know. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will print B. To make it more obvious on what your intent is, you could put AddressOf Me.Foo.  Also, just as an FYI, if you put MyClass.Foo, it will print A

```
    Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim b As B = New B
        b.PFoo() ' prints B
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class B
    Inherits A

    Protected Overrides Sub Foo()
        Console.WriteLine("B")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class A
    Public Sub PFoo()
        Dim f As Action = New Action(AddressOf Me.Foo)
        f.Invoke()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Foo()
        Console.WriteLine("A")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: and what if you put not Me. but `MyClass.Foo`...?

Comment: if you put MyClass.Foo instead of Me.Foo, you're providing the address to the method in Class A. In a class hierarchy, MyClass refers to the class in which it is used. For example, using MyClass.Foo in Class A will refer to the Foo method in Class A. However, using Me.Foo in the class hierarchy will look in derived classes that override the Foo method. If it cannot find any, it will invoke the Foo method in class A. So in this example, since Class B overrides Foo, it will be invoked when class A invokes Me.Foo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that PFoo will reference Foo that is overridden in the inheriting class, if PFoo is called within the inheriting B class's/object instance.

Comment: in other words, when calling `bInstance.PFoo()` it will output `B`?